# Build errors in datastore while using golang/protobuf

Tags: go, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore, protocol-buffers

I have an application which uses both bigquery and cloud datastore APIs. I use glide for go package management. I keep seeing build errors with either bigquery or datastore depending upon the version of golang/protobuf that I use. I am not able to find a version that is compatible with both bigquery and datastore. Either one of the packages keeps failing to build.

Build errors in datastore while using golang/protobuf version 7cc19b78d562895b13596ddce7aafb59dd789318:

> ../../vendor/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations/annotations.pb.go:33:
>   undefined: proto.ProtoPackageIsVersion2
>   ../../vendor/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations/annotations.pb.go:41:
>   unknown proto.ExtensionDesc field 'Filename' in struct literal
>   ../../vendor/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations/annotations.pb.go:48:
>   undefined: proto.RegisterFile
>   ../../vendor/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations/http.pb.go:540:
>   undefined: proto.RegisterFile Build errors in bigquery while using
>   golang/protobuf version 8ee79997227bf9b34611aee7946ae64735e6fd93:
>
> ../../vendor/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/params.go:55: undefined:
>   bigquery.QueryParameterType
>   ../../vendor/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/params.go:56: undefined:
>   bigquery.QueryParameterType
>   ../../vendor/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/params.go:57: undefined:
>   bigquery.QueryParameterType
>   ../../vendor/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/params.go:58: undefined:
>   bigquery.QueryParameterType
>   ../../vendor/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/params.go:59: undefined:
>   bigquery.QueryParameterType
>   ../../vendor/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/params.go:60: undefined:
>   bigquery.QueryParameterType
>   ../../vendor/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/params.go:61: undefined:
>   bigquery.QueryParameterType
>   ../../vendor/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/params.go:94: undefined:
>   bigquery.QueryParameter
>   ../../vendor/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/params.go:110: undefined:
>   bigquery.QueryParameterType
>   ../../vendor/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/params.go:178: undefined:
>   bigquery.QueryParameter

Opened an issue here - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/issues/475. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did the right thing by filing a bug, so hopefully that will be resolved soon. The most recent version of the cloud APIs adds support for [query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/release-notes#december_22_2016) but based on the error that you are seeing, one of the libraries was not updated properly.